# Do rangers effectively have Two Weapon Fighting and Ambidexterity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ranger

Can a Ranger in medium or light armor fight as if she had the **Ambidexterity** and **Two Weapon Fighting** feats?

Comment: Ambidexterity does not exist in 3.5

Comment: My bad... I did not know that Ambidexterity was removed. My GM said it was still there.

Comment: The feat can be patched back in by the GM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion to the point of not having read the 3.5e player's handbook?

The [3.5e ranger class](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/ranger.htm) can select a [combat style](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/ranger.htm#combatStyle) at second level. One of those two styles gets you the equivalent of the [two-weapon fighting feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#twoWeaponFighting) for free without having to meet prereqs.  There is no Ambidexterity feat in 3.5e.

So yes, at second level, IF you select the two-weapon combat fighting style instead of archery, with the caveat that there is no Ambidexterity.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer as I recall: Yes

Long answer: As long as said ranger has the class feature or two weapon feat.  I also seem to recall that in 3.5 Ambidexterity was removed as a feat and was just included in TWF.